# BertModel transformers outputs string instead of tensor

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm following [this](https://curiousily.com/posts/sentiment-analysis-with-bert-and-hugging-face-using-pytorch-and-python/) tutorial that codes a sentiment analysis classifier using BERT with the [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/) library and I'm having a very odd behavior. When trying the BERT model with a sample text I get a string instead of the hidden state. This is the code I'm using:

```
import transformers
from transformers import BertModel, BertTokenizer

print(transformers.__version__)

PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME = 'bert-base-cased'
PATH_OF_CACHE = "/home/mwon/data-mwon/paperChega/src_classificador/data/hugingface"

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME,cache_dir = PATH_OF_CACHE)

sample_txt = 'When was I last outside? I am stuck at home for 2 weeks.'

encoding_sample = tokenizer.encode_plus(
  sample_txt,
  max_length=32,
  add_special_tokens=True, # Add '[CLS]' and '[SEP]'
  return_token_type_ids=False,
  padding=True,
  truncation = True,
  return_attention_mask=True,
  return_tensors='pt',  # Return PyTorch tensors
)

bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME,cache_dir = PATH_OF_CACHE)


last_hidden_state, pooled_output = bert_model(
  encoding_sample['input_ids'],
  encoding_sample['attention_mask']
)

print([last_hidden_state,pooled_output])
```

that outputs:

```
4.0.0
['last_hidden_state', 'pooler_output']
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While the answer from [Aakash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65137768/6664872) provides a solution to the problem, it does not explain the issue. Since one of the 3.X releases of the transformers library, the models do not return tuples anymore but specific output objects:

```
o = bert_model(
    encoding_sample['input_ids'],
    encoding_sample['attention_mask']
)
print(type(o))
print(o.keys())
```

Output:

```
transformers.modeling_outputs.BaseModelOutputWithPoolingAndCrossAttentions
odict_keys(['last_hidden_state', 'pooler_output'])
```

You can return to the previous behavior by adding `return_dict=False` to get a tuple:

```py
o = bert_model(
   encoding_sample['input_ids'],
   encoding_sample['attention_mask'],
   return_dict=False
)

print(type(o))
```

Output:

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

I do not recommend that, because it is now unambiguous to select a specific part of the output without turning to the documentation as shown in the example below:

```py
o = bert_model(encoding_sample['input_ids'],  encoding_sample['attention_mask'], return_dict=False, output_attentions=True, output_hidden_states=True)
print('I am a tuple with {} elements. You do not know what each element presents without checking the documentation'.format(len(o)))

o = bert_model(encoding_sample['input_ids'],  encoding_sample['attention_mask'], output_attentions=True, output_hidden_states=True)
print('I am a cool object and you can acces my elements with o.last_hidden_state, o["last_hidden_state"] or even o[0]. My keys are; {} '.format(o.keys()))
```

Output:

```
I am a tuple with 4 elements. You do not know what each element presents without checking the documentation
I am a cool object and you can acces my elements with o.last_hidden_state,  o["last_hidden_state"] or even o[0]. My keys are; odict_keys(['last_hidden_state', 'pooler_output', 'hidden_states', 'attentions'])
```

Comment: Indeed, I recommend always using `return_dict=True` so that the outputs can be retrieved unambiguously from the dictionary returned by the model.

Comment: How to decode the output of bertmodel to get the sentence or string?

Comment: The output of the bert_model is just a contextualized representation of your input and the sentence is still the same. You can simply perform `tokenizer.decode(input_ids)`. In case you have a different layer on top of bert, this is different. Please open your own question in that case. @shaikmoeed

Comment: @cronoik, can you share how to convert model output back to text? I assume this output contains features in tensor form and I would like to see it as a text

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue while learning how to implement Bert. I noticed that using

```
last_hidden_state, pooled_output = bert_model(encoding_sample['input_ids'], encoding_sample['attention_mask'])
```

is the issue. Use:

```
outputs = bert_model(encoding_sample['input_ids'], encoding_sample['attention_mask'])
```

and extract the last_hidden state using

```
output[0]
```

You can refer to the documentation [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertmodel) which tells you what is returned by the BertModel

Comment: How to convert model output back to text? I assume this output contains features in tensor form and I would like to see it as a text